# Simple time series analysis with R: aggregating and subsetting

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

I want to convert monthly data into quarterly averages. These are my 2 datasets:

```
gas <- UKgas
dd <- UKDriverDeaths
```

I was able to accomplish (I think) for the `dd` data as so:

```
dd.zoo <- zoo(dd)
ddq <- aggregate(dd.zoo, as.yearqtr, mean)
```

However I cannot figure out how to do this with the `gas` data...any help?

---

**Follow-up**

When I try to subset the data based on date (1969-1984) the resulting data does not include 1969 Q1 and instead includes 1985 Q1...any suggestions on how to fix this? I was just trying to subset as `gas[1969:1984]`.

Comment: wow my fault. so when I try to subset the data based on date (1969-1984) the resulting data does not include 1969 Q1 and instead includes 1985 Q1...any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Thank you so much! I was just trying to subset as so: gas['1969::1984']

Answer (score 3):

Originally I did not plan to post answer, as it looks like you did not pre-check your `UKgas` dataset to see that it is already a quarterly time series.

But the follow-up question is worth answering. "ts" object comes with many handy generic functions. We can use `window` to easily subset a time series. To extract the section between first quarter of 1969 and the final quarter of 1984, we can use

```
window(UKgas, start = c(1969,1), end = c(1984,4))
```

The result will still be a quarterly time series.

On the other hand, if we use "[" for subsetting, we lose object class:

```
class(UKgas[1:12])
#[1] "numeric"
```